# Regarding External Accessory framework usage for an iPad application

Tags: ios, sdk

I researched a bit on External Accessory framework`s usage.
I am not able to understand the command protocol that has to be followed by the external device made by the manufacturer(that is under "Made for iPad developer program").
Is this command protocol different from the normal protocols we use in iPhone application programming?
Given below are trhe links I refered to:

[What are the protocols supported in Iphone's External Accessory Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083453/what-are-the-protocols-supported-in-iphones-external-accessory-framework)

http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/09/14/communicating-with-external-devices-from-the-iphone-and-ipad/

[How to launch an iphone app when an external accessory is either paired over BT or plugged into dock connector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5734222/how-to-launch-an-iphone-app-when-an-external-accessory-is-either-paired-over-bt)

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Are you an MFI developer?